# xterm on sles 11.2

Tags: xterm, suse

I am trying to get xterm to work on sles 11.2. I did it recently on 10.3 and it was really simple but nothing works on 11.2.

On 10.3 I installed xterm on the server and ran xming for windows on my local PC. Then from a putty went to SSH > X11 > Enable X11 forwarding. When I connected to the server I could run xterm and it worked straight away.

However, when I do the same thing on Sles 11.2 and I try and run xterm it says the display isn't set.

Is there something special I need to do for 11.2 to make it work. There isn't any firewalls enabled so this isn't the problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**
I have changed the SSH config files as suggested by twalberg but still no luck.

In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config I have the following`

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
   ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config I have the following`

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

I then restarted ssh using `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` and then performed the same steps as mentioned in the question with putty but still getting the display not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find out the problem. I need to install x-core package in yast. Didn't need to do this in sles 10.3 but apparently for 11.2 you do.

Thanks all for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `sshd` on your 11.2 box is configured to not allow X11 forwarding for security reasons. It needs to be enabled on the client side (which you are doing) and on the server side (in `sshd_config`) for it to work, so you might need to tweak the config on the SLES system.

Comment: Thanks I've added some info about what I tried with your suggestion, still having no luck with it.

Comment: Try also going into Session->Logging and select "SSH Packets". Then after you've connected, in the `putty.log` that was created you should find a couple different packets marked SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST - one that has 'x11-req' in the packet and one that has 'pty-req'. After the CHANNEL_REQUEST for the x11-req, is the next packet SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS, or something else?